# How to distribute (vocal) training time for most effective learning?

Tags: voice, practice, learning, voice-training

(If you’re not a singer, but have experience with learning other skills or some knowlegde about learning in general, your answer might also be helpful.)

Let’s say you have 7 hours of practice time per week. How would you distribute them across the week for optimal learning?

E.g. 1h per day / 2h every 2nd day / 1h24min for five days, two days off / 30 min two times a day / 20 min three times a day etc.

My vocal practice comprises a lot of different subskills and techniques. So the question is not only, how to distribute the total training time, but, maybe most importantly, how to distribute the time of practicing different techniques and subskills across the training time. According to your experience, what is the optimal balance between repetition rate and practice duration per workout for individual subskills?

E.g. dedicate every day to a different skill in depth with several days between alike workouts / Practice each skill briefly, only doing the most important exercises, but repeat this every day etc.

Comment: After a couple of visits to a good teacher, he or she will be in a far better position to address these issues than many strangers on the internet.

Comment: This is going to be different for everyone.  It depends on what specific areas you are having challenges with, what type of learning curve you have, and what type of learning style appeals to you.  All in all, you will not get objective answers.

Comment: I think the efficiency of training and learning greatly depends on having a concrete use for the skills. The time required to learn arbitrary things just for the sake of learning arbitrary things is completely different from, say, the time required to learn something to save your life. What's your motivation behind this? Which aspects of singing do you need them most? Is there something you want to do, something you particularly want to excel in? If think you should have an idea of where you want to go and why.

Comment: @piiperi I agree that it is important to answer these questions for oneself, to set priorities, to have goals and to have a motivating force. However, I don't see how this is relevant for the answer to my question.

Comment: My comment was about learning in general. Get a gig or something, record your singing, make it count. "This is not a drill" type of situation.

Comment: @FidRewe, piiperi is correct your goals are related to your time management.  It is not fair to expect a formulaic response to this.  7h/w is not a lot of time.  2 things come to mind, (1) a little every day is better than 3.5h 2xs a week, (2) you can sing anywhere so how are you confined to only 7h/w?

Comment: @ggcg
Ad (1) On this level, it's also clear to me that the first is better, but is it still benefical to split daily practice time into blocks? How far to split practice time for optimal results?
Ad (2) I'm not confined to 7 hours. It's just some amount of time that you could take as given in order to answer my question. How many hours would you workout in the gym each week?

Comment: @ggcg
Ad (2) Vocal training is muscle training as well, so you will run into overtraining pretty fast. For beginners, it is often required to practice 20-30 minutes a day. In my opinion, 7 hours a week is a reasonable amount of time to practice, if you have rather well-developped muscles and good technique. Maybe it would be worth doubling the amount of practice, but the longer the practice time, the less efficient it would become, as I wouldn't be able to maintain a clear focus, the brain would get closer to saturation and eventually the vocals would get overused.

Comment: I hope you are taking lessons.  I think some of your assumptions and comparisons are a little off.  Singing is not quite like going to the gym.  Unless you are not doing it right you can go longer than a workout and not suffer.  On the other hand if your throat hurts or something you should stop and ask your teacher for help getting correct technique.  Singing properly requires developing the correct posture and that requires muscle memory but not muscle exhaustion like body building.

Comment: As for me, my vocal teacher spend about 45min of a hour lesson on technical exercises and the last 15min on a piece of music.  That seems like a switch but she expects me to devote more time at home on actual music.  To compare with other musicians, Segovia was known to spend about 4 hours a day on technique alone before moving on to performance pieces.  An 8 hour day at least.  Perhaps too much for a beginner but I assert that if your technique is correct you will not over work your muscles.  Another option is to break up practice time into 1/2 h chunks dispersed in the day.